# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, function

I was trying to create a to-do list where with help of one input tag I wanted to enter all todo lists by adding HTML dynamically but while removing, I thought to remove it from the opposite order and later to implement it differently;
if I press the remove button I was getting an error in the console part as shown in this image:[image: the 24th line in my pc code becomes the 17th line in the bellow mentioned code];
can anyone find the problem in my code, if I test only that remove function separately then that works but not in bellow mentioned code [image: image of whole code]

```
<body>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div id="li">
    <input type="text" id="liin" name="in"/> 
    <button name="add" onclick=add()  className="btn btn-light">add</button> 
</div>

<script>
var i =1;
function add() {
    let temp = document.getElementById('liin').value;   
    document.getElementById('li').innerHTML+=`<br><span id="divli${i}">${temp}</span>  
    <button name="add" onclick=remove()  className="btn btn-light">remove</button>`; 
    i++;  
}
function remove() {
    document.getElementById(`divli${i}`).innerHTML ='';
     i--;strong text
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: because the `i` is one greater than the element you just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You are incrementing the i value too late in the code so your reference to select the element is coming in a null.
Another thing you'll want to do is add a class to each 'remove' button to be selected and removed in the remove function as well. This can be done dynamically as well.

```html
<body>
<div>Hello world</div>
<div id="li">
    <input type="text" id="liin" name="in"/> 
    <button name="add" onclick=add()  className="btn btn-light">add</button> 
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
function add() {
    i++;
    let temp = document.getElementById('liin').value;   
    document.getElementById('li').innerHTML+=`<br><span id="divli${i}">${temp}</span>  
    <button name="add" onclick=remove() id="divli${i}"  className="btn btn-light">remove</button>`;   
}
function remove() {
    // document.getElementById(`divli${i}`).innerHTML = '';
    let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(`#divli${i}`);
    nodeList.forEach(node => node.remove());
    i--;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: your code works like butter, but I'm unable to understand the forEach part specially node.remove(), what node (are they elements in nodeList), is nodeList an array if yes how it is stored, if not how will forEach work, is node.remove() an recursive function or what I'm unable to understand  can you please simplify it to make my beginner brain understandable

Comment: To understand it better, go ahead and console.log(nodeList) after its initialization. Queryselectors return nodelists instead of HTMLCollections. To put it simply, a nodelist is an array of all the html items with the id you were searching for. You then use the built in forEach method which performs an action on each element(or node) in the array (nodelist). I then simply remove each item from the list which removes it from the DOM. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is that node.remove() A inbuilt function?

Comment: Yep! Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove